# Error: Received unknown parameter: business_type - Node Stripe Connect

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

So I am trying to create a Stripe Connect account using a Firestore trigger function (onUpdate), but I keep getting the error: `Error: Received unknown parameter: business_type` in my Firebase Function logs. 
This makes me feel like I have poorly formatted the `stripe.accounts.create()` call. I followed the [Stripe docs here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create?lang=node). I got it working if I just include the values `type`, `country`, and `email`, but would like to include all important values right off the bat, but maybe I have to update other values after the account is created by stripe? If so is there a way to update these more values in the `function(error, account)` call below? Not a whole lot of example code I can find for this, so if anyone has worked with this and has some tips that would be great!

**Snippet:**

```
const response = await stripe.accounts.create({ 
  type: 'custom',
  country: 'US',
  // Optional Values
  requested_capabilities: ['platform_payments'],
  email: newValue.email,
  // tos_acceptance: newValue.stripeTosAcceptance,
  business_type: 'individual',
  individual: {
    //some other options values we could include (see docs)
    // address? Gender? default currency? verification docs?
    first_name: newValue.firstName,
    last_name: newValue.lastName,
    ssn_last_4: newValue.ssnLast4,
    dob: {
      day: newValue.dob.day,
      month: newValue.dob.month,
      year: newValue.dob.year
    }
  },
}, function(error, account) {
  if(error){
    console.log("Error: " + error);
  } else {
    console.log("Writing account.id to user DB...");
    admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(context.params.userId)
      .set({ connect_id: account.id }, { merge: true });
  }
});
```

Comment: When does this error happen? If the functions is deployed or during deployment?

Comment: When the function is deployed to firebase, but on that note, perhaps there is a better way to test my function than deploying them to firebase every time?

Comment: What version of the Stripe API is your account using? The way that Stripe handles connect accounts changed significantly very recently. I recommend upgrading your account to the latest and I suspect that will fix the issue. https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2019-02-19

Comment: Do you use Typescript? As @duck mentioned there were some recent changes and the `@types/stripe` type definitions are not updated. You could try `npm i @types/stripe` maybe they have added the missing types. Or you have to modify the type definition yourself. Had this problem with the Payment Intent API recently.

Comment: package.json states `"@types/stripe": "^6.25.11", "stripe": "^6.26.0",` after running `npm i @types/stripe; npm install stripe;`, redeployed with `firebase deploy --only functions:createStripeAccount` and still getting the same error. What version of Stripe should I be seeing for that newest update? Thanks for the tips btw, I feel like this might be on the right trail!

Comment: Update: I went to my Stripe dashboard to upgrade the API version and it fixed that error! Thanks guys! (See https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades)

Comment: @DangerDoug I did not know about this API upgrade functionality, just started recently with Stripe. Thanks for the feedback could be useful in the near future. You should post your solution as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @duck and @Sebe suggested, I went to the Stripe dashboard to upgrade the API version and it fixed that error! (See stripe.com/docs/upgrades) Seems Stripe recently changed/updated the values expected for the `stripe.accounts.create()` function, which was why the value mismatched the docs.